# How do I set the ImageView in Android Dialogs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-image, android-dialog

I am trying to display an image in an android dialog. If I select an image from the gallery app it should be displayed in a dialog. I have tried to fetch the selected image from the gallery app and passed its path to an alert dialog.

Comment: its like what app image send process....

Comment: Do you only want to know how to set image in alert dialog box? Or how to fetch image from gallery as well?

Comment: i know to fetch image from galley.. and i want the how to set selected image in alert box @ShashankUdupa

Comment: please show us what You have done until now and where You stuck...in code.....

Comment: first i will created one custom layout with image view ..

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenWidth = size.x;
        int screenHeight = size.y;Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
  BitmapDrawable resizedBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, false));

Comment: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.imageindialog);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.goProDialogImage);
   image.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(selectedImagePath));
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        dialog.show();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder ImageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
ImageDialog.setTitle("Title");
ImageView showImage = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
ImageDialog.setView(showImage);

ImageDialog.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
    {   
    }
});
ImageDialog.show();
```

Comment: Yes! This solution is the simplest I've seen yet, and it works well.

Answer (score 4):

hey follow this [link..](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

First you have to set your custom dialog layout to your dialog box, like below.

`setcontentview(R.layout.custom)`
and set the image with `setImageResources(your image id)`

```
    // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: i will tried the above sample but i need to set image ,from galley not drawble

Comment: tell clearly bro..like in whats app you want..@VigneshwaranT

Comment: i am developing chat application .. i am trying to do if user want to send image to another user ,user select the image from gallery ,that have i will done, i user clicks the image from galley , selected image will shows in alert dialog with two button likes "Send","Cancel" @Narendra Baratam

Comment: Oh, got it..@VigneshwaranT

Comment: did you find your solution

Comment: post your solution, and accept it as an answer, you will get reputation.@VigneshwaranT

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageindialog, null);
        ImageView imageView1(ImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.goProDialogImage);
     imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath));
builder.setView(dialogView);

Comment: hey @VigneshwaranT, not here man..click on add answer button and post this code, and you can see the right answer logo, mark it as answer. Then you will get reputation,..what i mean is if you find your ans by own, then post the ans and mark it.

Answer (score 4):

For setting image in an alert dialog box you need to create a custom dialog like this

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/my_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity show your custom dialog box like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
builder.setView(dialogView)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.create, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).create().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> I use this simple method for showing **AlertDialog**:

```
private void showAlertDialog(Context mContext, String mTitle, String mBody, int mImage){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setIcon(mImage);
        if(mTitle.length()>0)
            builder.setTitle(mTitle);
        if(mBody.length()>0)
            builder.setTitle(mBody);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
```

> call method:

```
showAlertDialog(mContext, "OOPS!", getString(R.string.massage_nointernet), R.drawable.ic_no_internet);
```