# How do I include an image in a dialog with cordova-plugin-dialogs?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am using the `cordova-plugin-dialogs` plugin for PhoneGap and according to discussions I found, it's possible to include images in the dialogs, but I haven't been able to find how. I tried HTML code in the message payload but it's not working. Anyone know?

The code:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    '<img src="path/to/file.jpg">', // message
     onConfirm,                     // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Upgrade',                      // title
    ['Upgrade Now','Cancel']        // buttonLabels
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think is not possible to add any image\html content to dialog generated by this plugin, it handle text only properties of native dialogs. 
To archive that you need to edit plugin source code and add any image to android/ios native dialog class, then pass image path via javascript paramer (or harcode its path).

Look for example at native implementation of android in your plugin: [Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/src/android/Notification.java)

You need to add something like this at line 170 of plugin to set any image in native dialog: [How to set image view in android dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570805/how-to-set-image-view-in-android-dialog-box)

Same thing for IOS and WP.

Hope i was helpful.

**Edit:** in plugin pull request on GIT repository i have found a pull for add HTML support, then also you can try to merge this pull in plugin source and send HTML image to dialog content (only for **alert** type dialog): [add support for html message in alert](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/pull/68)